# Open Form from another project

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working in project A, and I want to open Form F from Project B.
I know that you can import B to project A and do `B.FormF().Show()`, but this is very inefficient because I have to import the whole project into my other project.

So, my question is if there is an other and more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Why do you think this would be inefficient?

Comment: @FlorianGreinacher Because Project B is a very large project

Comment: Clearly you do not understand how projects work, c# or otherwise

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want to reference it you must import it.

However it is only an impact on build, assuming both are deployed anyway (or else you wouldn't be calling it) so just add the reference. It isn't inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Compile project B and then reference the .dll file.
2. Just transfer the form to project A.

I can't think of anything else.